# Why was this Discovery episode named "Unification III"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

The name of S03E07 of *Star Trek: Discovery* is **Unification III**. The *Unification* word has some connection with the story, but what does the suffix *III* signify?

Comment: I am currently on the go, so no time to write a full answer, but this episode is related to the two parter "Unification": https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unification_II_(episode)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There have been two episodes in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*:

- [Unification I, S05E07](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unification_I_(episode))
- [Unification II, S05E08](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unification_II_(episode))

In these episodes, Spock travels to Romulus in order to reunite the Romulans and Vulcans as one people.

The synopsis of the episodes from the respective *Memory Alpha* articles linked above:

> Unification I
>
> To the Federation's surprise, Ambassador Spock has traveled to Romulus. Fearing he has defected, they send Captain Picard and Data on a covert mission to determine why.
>
> Unification II
>
> On Romulus, Picard and Data meet with Spock, who claims to be trying to reunite the Romulans and Vulcans. While Spock works to achieve his goal, powers within the Romulan government seek to pervert his mission into an invasion of the Federation.

So, the reunited Romulans and Vulcans are a result of what Spock did, therefore Unification III.

Comment: Also, the theme of the Discovery episode is about reuniting Ni'Var with the Federation.

Comment: Of course since Discovery happens before TNG it would be more fun to call the episode Unification 0.

Comment: Though that means if Discovery wants another Unification episode it has to be Unification 0.5 which is a bit messy.

Comment: @Daron But time travel.

Comment: @Daron Discovery begins before TOS and TNG, but season 3 takes place in the far far future.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah okay. Just me being a silly sausage (as usual).